# Genogram creation software for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

Is any Ubuntu app for genogram charts creation like [GenoPro](http://www.genopro.com)?

Answer (score 0):

#### [WinGeno](http://wingeno.org/)

This a programme originally developed for Windows that can be installed on Linux.

> WinGeno is a free computer program to create diagrams of family
>   constellations in form of genograms. The representation of particulars
>   family members depends on the established symbols. WinGeno does not
>   represent social nor emotional relationships.
>
> Supported systems: Windows 2000 and higher, Mac OS and Linux.
>   Supported languages: English and German.

To run on Linux it requires Mono:

> WinGeno needs Mono 4.6 or higher as prerequisite. To prepare your
>   Linux distribution you need to adhere to the installation description
>   as mentioned here.